# Need to design query or MS SQL procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Lets say I have 2 tables

Student_table:

```
studentID, lname, fname
```

Test_table:

```
testid, studentid, testname, testdate
```

There are 2 tests student can take Test A and Test B.

Now I want to design a query or a procedure which allows to display data from student table and test_table with condition if student has taken both Test A.

Only test A info needs to displayed along with student info otherwise any test taken info should be displayed or no test info should be displayed if no test available.

Comment: I suggest that you set up a proper many to many relationship between tests and students.  If you don't know how, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 0):

what I understood is, if student took both the tests, then you go to show student info and test A info , otherwise the test taken with student info.
If my understanding is correct, try this query.

```
select st.*,tt.* 
from student_table st 
inner join test_table tt 
    on st.sid = tt.sid 
    and tt.sid in (select sid 
                   from test_table 
                   where testname ='testA' 
                  intersect 
                   select sid 
                   from test_tablewhere testname ='testB') 
    and testname='testA'
union all
select st.*,tt.* 
from student_table st 
inner join test_table tt 
    on st.sid = tt.sid
    and tt.sid not in (select sid 
                       from test_table 
                       where testname ='testA' 
                      intersect 
                       select sid 
                       from test_table 
                       where testname ='testB') ;
```